# Conditional WHERE clause with CASE statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I'm brand-new to the Oracle world so this could be a softball.  In working with an SSRS report, I'm passing in a string of states to a view.  The twist is that the users could also pick a selection from the state list called "[ No Selection ]" ... (that part was not by doing and I'm stuck with implementing things this way)

If they choose the No Selection option, then I just want to return all states by default, otherwise return just the list of states that are in my comma-separated list.

This really seems like it should be easy but I'm stuck.  Here is the code I have so far (just trying to get a sample to work) but my eyes have finally gone crossed trying to get it going.

Could anybody give me some direction on this one please?

```
begin
  :stateCode:='MO,FL,TX';
  --:stateCode:='[ No Selection ]';
end;
/

select count(*) as StateCount, :stateCode as SelectedVal
from hcp_state vw
where 
  (case 
      when (:stateCode = '') then (1)
      when (:stateCode != '') then (vw.state_cd in (:stateCode))
      (else 0)
  end)
;
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can write the `where` clause as:

```
where (case when (:stateCode = '') then (1)
            when (:stateCode != '') and (vw.state_cd in (:stateCode)) then 1
            else 0)
       end = 1;
```

Alternatively, remove the `case` entirely:

```
where (:stateCode = '') or
      ((:stateCode != '') and vw.state_cd in (:stateCode));
```

Or, even better:

```
where (:stateCode = '') or vw.state_cd in (:stateCode)
```

Comment: `(else 0)` should not have brackets.

Comment: In Oracle, you need to use `is null` not `= ''`.  But the principle is correct.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a [CASE statement in WHERE clause](https://www.oraask.com/2021/08/oracle-case-statement.html#Oracle-Case-Statement-in-WHERE-Clause-Example) as:

```
SELECT employee_no, name, department_no
FROM   emps
WHERE  (CASE
          WHEN :p_dept_no = 50 THEN 0
          WHEN :p_dept_no = 70 THEN 0
          ELSE -1
        END) = 0;
```