# Conditional where statement and comparison operator

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I'm trying to reduce the size of my sql `where` statement to eliminate redundant clauses "remove the `union` statements.

**My statement is like this:**

```
SELECT
   col1, col2, col3...etc
FROM
   someTabe
WHERE
   col1 = :param
   and :sType = 1
UNION
SELECT
   col1, col2, col3...etc
FROM
   someTabe
WHERE
   col1 like '%'||:param||'%'
   and :sType = 2
```

The problem with this statement is that for each `:sType` possibility, I have to write a select statement and union all the possibilities, and in my case, my sql statements are very long and complicated even without a union

So I have tried to re-write the where statement to something like this:

```
SELECT
   col1, col2, col3...etc
FROM
   someTabe
WHERE
   CASE WHEN :sType = 1 then col1= :param ELSE col1 like '%'||:param||'%' END
```

But this fails to run, it needs an operator after the case statement as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104884/conditional-where-clause-with-case-statement-in-oracle)

So, is there a syntax that can achieve the idea in the above statement?

Comment: can't you just use OR: for ex: WHERE (col1 = :param and :sType = 1) OR (col1 like '%param%' and sType = 2)...??

Comment: @Zeina, I honestly don't know why I didn't think of the OR statement, I usually tend to avoid OR and I was overthinking of the solution, I think I deserve a down vote xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple or might be enough.

```
SELECT
   col1, col2, col3...etc
FROM
   someTabe
WHERE
   (:sType = 1 and col1 = :param )
or (:sType = 2 and col1 like '%'||:param||'%')
```

Example of how to use case:
[Conditional WHERE clause with CASE statement in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104884/conditional-where-clause-with-case-statement-in-oracle)

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that!