# How to use case statement in where condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use the CASE statement in the WHERE clause like:

```
WHERE  p.resource_qry_seq = b.resource_qry_seq
AND    p.resource_id = b.resource_id
AND    (CASE
         WHEN b.flexible_time IS NULL THEN
          ((b.activity_start >= p.activity_start AND b.activity_end < p.activity_end) OR
          (b.activity_start > p.activity_start  AND b.activity_end <= p.activity_end))
         ELSE
               b.activity_start > p.late_start
         END)
```

I'm getting, 'missing right parenthesis' How to include such conditions according to a value in a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate of a `CASE` expression (i.e. what comes after `THEN`) has to be a value, rather than logic.  You can rephrase your `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
WHERE
    p.resource_qry_seq = b.resource_qry_seq AND
    p.resource_id = b.resource_id AND
    ((b.flexible_time IS NULL AND
        (b.activity_start >= p.activity_start AND b.activity_end < p.activity_end) OR
        (b.activity_start > p.activity_start  AND b.activity_end <= p.activity_end)) OR
    (b.flexible_time IS NOT NULL AND b.activity_start > p.late_start))
```